# linkerd: crashloopbackoff kubernetes pod error while setting failure accrual

Tags: kubernetes, linkerd

Configured my yml with failure accrual circuit breaking, with below config as reference.
https://github.com/linkerd/linkerd-examples/blob/master/failure-accrual/linkerd.yml

```
client:
    failureAccrual:
      kind: io.l5d.consecutiveFailures
      failures: 5
      backoff:
        kind: constant
        ms: 10000
```

After applying the changes, I see the pods in crashloopbackoff state.

```
kubectl  apply -f ./linkerd-fa.yml
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Crashloopbackoff` means that the process is failing to start.  If you use `kubectl logs pod/$POD_ID l5d`, you should see an error message.  I'm guessing there's a formatting issue with your configuration that is causing linkerd to error out during startup.

Comment: Simple thing, indeed was issue with format. was beginner when I started :)

Answer (score 1):

Linkerd provides failure accrual by default as part of each of your client configurations. The [default failure accrual configuration](https://linkerd.io/config/head/linkerd/index.html#client-parameters) is 5 consecutive failures, which is also what you've pasted in the YAML snippet with your question. So in this case you could omit the failureAccrual setting altogether from your config and the behavior will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should delete the pods which is **Crashloopbackoff** and then run `kubectl get pods`.